# jQuery: Toggle between two radio buttons on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to toggle the checked value between two radio buttons when the user presses a specific key (in this case its 'd'), but can only get it working in one direction.

HTML:

```
          <label>
            <input type="radio" id='dark-mode-on' name="dark-mode" />
            <span>On</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" id='dark-mode-off' name="dark-mode" checked />
            <span>Off</span>
          </label>
```

JS: (this is being called on keydown)

```
function toggleDarkModeRadio() {
  if ($('#dark-mode-on').prop('checked', true)) {
    $('#dark-mode-off').prop('checked', true);
  };
  if ($('#dark-mode-off').prop('checked', true)) {
    $('#dark-mode-on').prop('checked', true);
  };
}
```

But this only toggles the radio once from 'off' to 'on', and won't go back to 'off' again.

Ive tried a lot of variations and I can't get anything working better than this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is that the code in your function doesn't have breaks in it, so when it enters, if it's off, it skips the first if, then goes into the second one. However, if it enters that function and it's on currently, it will go into the first if, set it to off, then by the time it makes it to the second if, it's now off, so it goes in an turns it on again. You can adjust your function to use an else if, or a return like this:

```js
function toggleDarkModeRadio() {
  if ($('#dark-mode-on').prop('checked')) {
    $('#dark-mode-off').prop('checked', true);
    return;
  };
  if ($('#dark-mode-off').prop('checked')) {
    $('#dark-mode-on').prop('checked', true);
    return;
  };
}
```

or this:

```js
function toggleDarkModeRadio() {
  if ($('#dark-mode-on').prop('checked')) {
    $('#dark-mode-off').prop('checked', true);
  }
  else if ($('#dark-mode-off').prop('checked')) {
    $('#dark-mode-on').prop('checked', true);
  };
}
```

The other issue is the use of setting the properties in the tested part of the if statement, this causes those properties to be set every time rather than check if they're set.

Comment: Those `if()` contain jQuery objects not booleans

Comment: Good catch, completely missed that

Comment: thanks heaps for the great explanation to help me understand what my error was. even though im using @Kalimah 's answer in my code for its brevity, this was still the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you have two radio inputs you can simplify your code to this:

```js
function toggleDarkModeRadio() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').prop("checked", true);
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.key != 'd')
    return;

  toggleDarkModeRadio();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
   <input type="radio" id='dark-mode-on' name="dark-mode" />
   <span>On</span>
 </label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" id='dark-mode-off' name="dark-mode" checked />
   <span>Off</span>
 </label>
```

Comment: very simple, i like it. i have a couple radios on the same page so I just changed type=radio to name=dark-mode and its perfect. thanks

Comment: sorry but i accepted @Rodentman87 s answer. you both posted working answers, but his post was overall the most helpful. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're not really testing whether the radio buttons are `checked` but rather you're setting them to `checked` in the `if` conditions.

And, as @charlietfl has explained below convert the `if()`s to one `if()`:

```
if ( $('#dark-mode-on').prop('checked') ) {
    $('#dark-mode-off').prop('checked', true);
} else if ( $('#dark-mode-off').prop('checked') ) {
    $('#dark-mode-on').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Which may be shortened to:

```
$('input[name="dark-mode"]:not(:checked)').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Still have issues with the sequential `if()`. If first condition is true will check the `off` radio.....and next `if` will be true and check the `on` again

Comment: Indeed! Thank you @charlietfl